# Undefined local variable inside a Struct in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class as follow:

```
class TempUser < Struct.new(:user)

    user.attributes.keys.each do |attribute|
        delegate attribute, to: :user
    end
end
```

When I try to use it in rails console I get:

```
$> tmp = TempUser.new(User.last)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for TempUser:Class
```

But if I replace `user.attributes` by `User.new.attributes` it works.

It's not due to the loop, actually I get the same error by simply doing:

```
class TempUser < Struct.new(:user)
  test = user
end
```

I guess I missed something but I have no clue what it is, any idea?

EDIT

It might not be relevant in my example, but for my needs I will need the users' attributes, so I can't stay with something like `User.columns.map(&:name)`.

Comment: have you tried using `:user.attributes.keys.each` instead of `user.attributes.keys.each`?

Comment: :user is a Symbol it can't work

Comment: what are you expecting `user` to be? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I expect `user` to be an `User` instance, forget about the `delegate`, I just don't understand why I can't access `user` variables. Is it not like an argument that you would give to a method?

Comment: you can access `user` variable in struct method, not in class itself

Answer (score 0):

You have this error, because when ruby parse this class it understand `user` as class variable that is clear from error message: `'user' for TempUser:Class`

And `:user` it is an instance variable:

```
TempUser = Struct.new(:user)
tmp = TempUser.new(User.last)
=> #<struct TempUser user=#<User id: 1>>
```

All users have the same attributes, I think you can use something like this: `User.columns.map(&:name)`

EDIT

If each user may have different attributes, I think you can do it with `method_missing`

```
TempUser = Struct.new(:user) do
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
    return user.send(m) if user.respond_to?(m)
    super
  end
end
```